# How to use a define in a header file of a Cmake generated library?

Tags: xcode, cmake, include, static-libraries

I have an Xcode project "App" which references another Xcode project "Lib".

The "Lib" project is generated by Cmake. I use "add_definitions(-DMYDEFINE)" to set a define. This define is used in a `.h` and a `.cpp` file in my lib project.

The problem is the header (`.h`) file. If I use it from within the Lib project, my define is set. If I use the file from my App project, the define is not set (header file of lib is in my include path).

This set/not set happens at the same time, although the header file is guarded with "#pragma once".

---

I need this define in the header file. Is there a way to organize things such that I can set the define only with Cmake in the Lib project?

Comment: Why not add the define to the header file? Alternatively, you could specify a second add_definitions( -DMYDEFINE ) to you App project.

Comment: In projects with a "convenience" library, I sometimes package up all the lib defines and include directories into single variables, then set them in the parent scope to be manually included by any applications built from the same CMake hierarchy.